# AMDGPU r9 270X and hardware acceleration

Tags: amdgpu

I have a problem.
I had install amdgpu driver from Padoka's stable ppa (https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) and in games I have no problems. But with video playback I have a problem with hardware accelartion.

`vainfo`:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 18.3.3 - padoka PPA for AMD Radeon(TM) HD 8800 Series (PITCAIRN, DRM 3.23.0, 4.15.0-46-generic, LLVM 7.0.0)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

List of supported profiles is very short!

I used [this instruction](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/wiki/Requirements)

Into `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 amdgpu.dpm=1"
```

I was try boot by Ubuntu LiveDVD and did `vainfo`:
[vainfo by Ubuntu LiveDVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFseU.jpg)

How can I fix it?

P.S. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS